# On the proof of the Bertrand theorem

Tags: classical-mechanics, orbital-motion, stability

I was following the proof of the Bertrand theorem on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_theorem), which is based on Goldstein "Classical mechanics" (2nd edition).
The explanation was clear upto Eq (3). But then it assumes Fourier series expansion in the form $\eta(\theta)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty h_n\cos(n\beta\theta)$. My question is how to verify this form.

This frequency $\beta$ is derived from the analysis of an infinitesimal deviation from the perfect circular motion. What I do not understand is the assumption that more general deviations from the circle always have to come with the same period. I also wonder why $\sin(n\beta\theta)$ terms are absent.